# English language macro for French version of MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I wrote a VBA procedure for a client who has the French version of Project. Besides the language difference in Project field names the macro also has some MsgBox and InputBox statements and of course comment lines in English. I could convert field names, messages and comments to French but then I lose the ability to easily troubleshoot or update the code. I'm looking for suggestions that will enable the client to use and understand the code but still allow me to made changes as necessary.

Anyone have any experience with this type of issue or perhaps some ideas?

One idea I have is to replicate the macro in French either as a separate macro or as a bloated version with duplicate statements in English and French but neither of those is very appealing.